# Is it possible give more weight to class with lesser data in object detection while training?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Suppose I have about 250000 images total with 5 classes and the actual no of objects  in all the photos  is as follows.
dog 20000   cat 17000hen 16000 cow 5000ox  2000
In such a problem the accuracy after training the model using tensor-flow model is as follows:
dog 90   cat 60 hen 50 cow 0.02ox  0.15 
Is it possible to increase the accuracy of the classes cow and ox? 
Can we train the model so that we can add more weightage to the classes which have lesser number of classes in the tensor-flow?
I am using transfer learning: Faster R-CNN with ResNet-101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most typical approach is to change your sampling ratio such that each batch you train on is sampling each class at the same rate. This means you will oversample the under-represented classes as you train. A reasonably easy way to do this in Tensorflow is by creating separate `Dataset` objects for each class and then merging them back together using `tf.data.Dataset.interleave` to combine them back together such that they are evenly sampled across classes.

It is also possible to multiple your loss by a constant vector, this would effectively change the learning rate per class, I'd go with the former option myself.